# Why is this in codesandbox undefined?

Tags: codesandbox

If I enter this into a typescript or javascript sandbox I get

console.log(this) // undefined

If I enter it in the google developer tools console it is window.

In tools this===window is true

In Sandbox it is false.

Any idea why this is not bound to window in the codesandbox.io?

Comment: To run your code Codesandbox uses ES6 modules in which `this` is `undefined` by specs.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `vanilla JS` sandbox then `this` will be undefined because of `ES6` as mentioned by @Sergei, so better go with a `Static HTML` sandbox